# Is storing sas code in macro variables recommended?

Tags: macros, sas

I have to revamp a SAS project in which there are macro variables such as the following:

```
%let myDate = intnx('month',today(),-1);
```

and later...

```
data temp;
  a = &myDate;
run;
```

I'm inclined to use `%sysfunc` instead:

```
%let myDate = %sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),-1));
```

But I'm wondering... is this a matter of preference or is there some sound reason to prefer one method over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For extremely large datasets, you might find that with this particular example, calling `intnx` once for every row to get the same value leads to poor performance vs. defining a macro variable once and re-using it indefinitely.

Rob Penridge has demonstrated that in this instance the overhead is likely to be negligible, but for more computationally intensive code this will obviously not always be the case. Your mileage may vary.

More generally, when you start storing code rather than just constants within macro variables, you have to start thinking quite carefully about certain things:

- What sort of macro quoting might or might not be required (particularly in a SAS/CONNECT environment when you need to `rsubmit` blocks of code using macro variables)
- Whether or not your macro variable contains semicolons or other characters that might cause unexpected interactions with other blocks of code
- Whether it contains macro references that you don't want to resolve until the code executes

Comment: Thanks for this insightful answer!

Comment: I think the performance issue is very misleading and should be removed.  It's likely to cause concern where none is warranted.  Calling a single function for every row, even on very large datasets, will have no noticable performance difference.

Comment: Just to quantify the performance issue - running it 100 million times, takes 33 seconds.  If you are processing a dataset with 100 million rows, it's likely that the datastep is going to be taking a lot lot longer than that.  An additional 30 seconds will be a drop in the bucket.  Code: `data _null_; do i = 1 to 100*1000000; x = intnx('month',today(),-1); end; run;`

Comment: @RobertPenridge Thank you for your input. Duly updated.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to consider the question of timing. If you use `%sysfunc()` then the function runs when the macro variable is created. If you just store the function call in the macro variable then the function actually does not execute until the data step is running.  And in this case since it is calling the `today()` function it will run for every observation.  If you start your data step just before midnight on the last day of the month you could end up with different values of A on different observations in the same dataset.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is the only one that addresses the issue of producing correct results.

Comment: @RobertPenridge It's a tough call, as user667489 had also good points. I'd call it a draw if that were even possible! :)

Answer (score 1):

These are two different things that you are talking about. The first code with %LET and DATA step will create a macro variable **myDate** without executing the INTNX function, but will create a Table with column **a**

But, the second revamped %LET statement will actually create just a macro variable with value of INTNX function executed.

So, it actually depends on **what the business requirement is** -
**To create a Table**
  OR
**create a Macro variable which can be created once and used used over and over again.**

Comment: I am aware of all of that. What I'm asking is if there are some caveats of using the first method which I might be unaware of.

Comment: What do you mean by caveats? In what sense?

Comment: @JasonV - As far I as I see there are no caveats and its a matter of preference and satisfying the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of personal preference.  Personally I like to use the `%sysfunc` approach as it allows me to debug/print the result without having to process any datasteps.

Really I'd say whatever allows for better readability and maintainability.  If you're working with people that hate using macros then consider using the simpler first approach.  Horses for courses.